# xor between two numbers (after hex to binary conversion)

Tags: matlab

i donot know why there is error in this coding:

```
hex_str1 = '5'
bin_str1 = dec2bin(hex2dec(hex_str1))
hex_str2 = '4'
bin_str2 = dec2bin(hex2dec(hex_str2))
c=xor(bin_str1,bin_str2)
```

the value of c is not correct when i transform the hex to binary by using the xor function.but when i used the array the value of c is correct.the coding is

```
e=[1 1 1 0];
f=[1 0 1 0];
g=xor(e,f)
```

what are the mistake in my first coding to xor of hec to binary value??anyone can help me find the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is applying [`xor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html) on two strings instead of actual numerical arrays.

For the [`xor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html) command, logical "0"s are represented by actual zero elements. Any non-zero elements are interpreted as logical "1"s.

When you apply `xor` on two strings, the numerical value of each character (element) is its ASCII value. From `xor`'s point of view, the zeroes in your string are not really zeroes, but simply non-zero values (being equal to the ASCII value of the character '0'),  which are interpreted as logical "1"s. The bottom line is that in your example you're xor-ing 111<sub>b</sub> and 111<sub>b</sub>, and so the result is 0.

The solution is to convert your strings to logical arrays:

```
num1 = (bin_str1 == '1');
num2 = (bin_str2 == '1');
c = xor(num1, num2);
```

To convert the result back into a string (of a binary number), use this:

```
bin_str3 = sprintf('%d', c);
```

... and to a hexadecimal string, add this:

```
hex_str3 = dec2hex(bin2dec(bin_str3));
```

Comment: if i want to convert the hexa to binary by 128 bits, is this ok??

Comment: @ellahFaris then use the following syntax: `dec2bin(..., 128)`

Comment: for the xor part is correct..but the output for the hex_str3 is wrong..the binary form for the input is wrong. the input is 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF, 128 bits...can you help me why??

Comment: this is the code of mine :hex_str1 = '00112233445566778888AABBCCDDEEFF'
bin_str1 = dec2bin(hex2dec(hex_str1),128)
hex_str2 = '000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F'
bin_str2 = dec2bin(hex2dec(hex_str2),128)

num1 = (bin_str1 == '1')
num2 = (bin_str2 == '1')
c = xor(num1, num2)
bin_strc = sprintf('%d', c);

d=sum(c)    after i did some verification for the conversion hex to binary, i get the wrong output for bin_str1 and bin_str2..i do not know why..

Answer (score 0):

it is really helpful, and give me the correct conversion while forming HMAC value in matlab...
but in matlab you can not convert string of length more than 52 character using bin2dec() function and similarly hex2dec() can not take hexadecimal character string more than 13 length.